# Self complementary cartesian products

Tags: graph-theory

Given two graphs $G$ and $H$  is there a nice way to check whether the cartesian product $G\Box H$ is self complementary without directly computing its complement and searching for isomorphism? For example, how can one show that $K_3\Box K_3$ is self complementary?

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question. One could show $K_3\Box K_3$ was self complementary by a couple of drawings.

Comment: @Chris godsil: Yes, thats why I said without computing the complement, may be using some arguments on the degrees of verices and using the fact that it is a cartesian product; and this is not a homework.